# Managing style file in ArcPy using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, layers, legend, api, python-3

I am trying to update a geoprocessing service that was in ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro. The geoprocessing services use a style file for its legend and I want to update certain legends but I have no idea how. Here is the snippet of the code that I am using.

```
    lyr = mapframe.listLayers(droughtLayerName)
    styleItem = arcpy.mapping.ListStyleItems(stylePath,"Legend Items")[0]
    Legend.updateItem(lyr,styleItem)
```

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more information than this. ArcMap didn't have `arcpy.mp`, so you've already updated away from `arcpy.mapping`, but where are you stuck? Porting the code? using the style file? What's the result of the code you've provided

Comment: In arc.mp I could not find the library named ListStyleItems.

Comment: @KHibma I am stuck because I cannot figure out a way to read the Style file in Arcpro 3 using arcpy.